# Applyed animation moves view to the top of screen

Tags: android-animation, objectanimator

To see my humidityImageView I need to scroll down a little bit.
When I apply this animation:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(humidityImageView, View.Y,40);
objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
objectAnimator.start();
```

it starts fromt the top of the screen, but not from the position of the humidityImageView in my ConstraintLayout.
How to make animation starts from the initial view position?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed is replace View.Y to View.TRANSLATION_Y